# iphone calls both if and else at the same time?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, if-statement

I need to determine what file type a file is and then perform a certain action for it. this seems to work fine for some types, however all media types such as videos and sound files get mixed up. I determine the file type by doing this:

```
   BOOL matchedMP3 = ([[rowValue pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"mp3"]);

   if (matchedMP3 == YES)
   {
    NSLog(@"Matched MP3");
            }
```

I do this for various file types and just define an "else" for all the others. Here's the problem though. The iPhone calls them both. Here's what the log reveals:

> 2010-05-11 18:51:12.421 Test [5113:207] Matched MP3
>
> 2010-05-11 18:51:12.449 Test [5113:207] Matched ELSE

I've never seen anything like this before.

This is my "matchedMP3" function:

```
  BOOL matchedMP3 = ([[rowValue pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"mp3"]);
   if (matchedMP3 == YES)
   {
    NSLog(@"Matched MP3");
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    self.directoryContent = [manager directoryContentsAtPath:documentsDirectory];
    
    NSString *errorMessage = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
    
    NSString *urlAddress = [errorMessage stringByAppendingString:rowValue];
    
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlAddress]];
    
    moviePlayer.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeDefault;
    
    moviePlayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    
    [moviePlayer play];
   }
```

and here's the else statement:

```
   else {
    NSLog(@"Matched ELSE");
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:rowValue forKey:@"rowValue"];
    
    NSString*rowValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"rowValue"];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    self.directoryContent = [manager directoryContentsAtPath:documentsDirectory];
    
    NSString *errorMessage = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
    
    NSString *urlAddress = [errorMessage stringByAppendingString:rowValue];
    
    webViewHeader.prompt = rowValue;
    
    [documentViewer setDelegate:self];
    
    NSString *encodedString = [urlAddress stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
    //Create a URL object.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedString];
    
    //URL Requst Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    
    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    [documentViewer loadRequest:requestObj];
    
    [navigationController pushViewController:webView animated:YES];
    
   }
```

I can't see a reason why it wouldn't work. What happens is that both the webview and the MediaPlayer toggle their own player, so they overlap and play their sound/video a few secs apart from each other.

Any help would be appreciated & thank for you taking the time to read through my code.

Comment: Any chance that in the MP3 case, it is calling the function recursively, either directly or indirectly?

Comment: Or is your test simply calling the function twice?

Comment: Seems impossible :). Only thing I can come up to is that, are you sure you don't have = instead of == somewhere? I had this once ...

if(x = YES) would go through nicely without any warnings...

Comment: Are you sure the method isn't being called multiple times? Both if and else will never fire one after another within the same statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Didn't you mistakenly do something like

```
  if(conditionA)
  {
  ...
  }
  if(conditionB)
  {
  ...
  }
  else
  {
  ....
  }
```

In this case, if `conditionA` is satisfied but `conditionB` is not, the else clause is executed, because the first if clause finishes at the second if. You would want

```
  if(conditionA)
  {
  ...
  }
  else if(conditionB)
  {
  ...
  }
  else
  {
  ....
  }
```

instead. Beware the `else if`.

By the way, you don't have to and shouldn't compare a `BOOL` against `YES`.

```
 if(matchedMP3)
```

is enough. Remember, `if` accepts a boolean expression inside. A boolean value is a boolean expression!

Comment: You are right, how could i have missed that? Thanks very much for helping me out :)

Comment: How could you have missed that?  It's a common mistake.  We've all done it.